# Get data from database using PHP, JQuery and AJAX in JSON format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm having trouble getting data from my database. My goal is to get all groups from my database and return them in JSON (in an alert box or whatever).

Now it won't convert to JSON and I am getting weird response text from the ajax call. If you need anything else to solve this problem, please do not hesitate to ask.

Here is what I did.

## PHP

```
$servername = "redacted";
$username = "redacted";
$password = "redacted";
$dbname = "redacted";

if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'getGroups' : getAllGroups();break;
    }
}

function getAllGroups() {

    $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM groups");

    while($row = $query->fetch_object()) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }

    echo "{\"results\":";
    echo json_encode($result);
    echo "}";

    $mysqli->close();
 }
```

## JS

```
function getPosts() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'functions.php',
        data: {action: 'getGroups'},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            var result = JSON.parse(output);
            result = result.resultaten;
            alert(result);
        }
    });
}

getPosts();
```

Thanks in advance,
Mistergrave.

Comment: what json response you get ?

Comment: you forget to declare `$result = array();` or `$result = [];`

Comment: The JSON ResponseText is rather huge and contains tables... Idk what it means though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay guys, I managed to solve everything. Apparently the php function couldn't find my credentials to log in to the database server because I defined them on top of the php file (and since javascript only executed the function, these credentials were undefined).

#### Solution:

---

I just copy-pasted the credentials at the start of each function so these were defined. And tadaah! It worked :).

---

Now I realize why the responseText was full of tables, because it started to return error tables about the connection.

I hope my explanation will help other people who have this issue as well.

Cheers, and thanks for all the helpfull answers, 
Mistergrave.

Answer (score 1):

No need for that extra `echo`s. Try with -

```
echo json_encode(array('results' => $result));
```

Instead of -

```
echo "{\"results\":";
echo json_encode($result);
echo "}";
```

No need for - `if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {`

`if(!empty($_POST['action'])) {` - do the all.

Define `$result` first.

```
$result = array();
while($row = $query->fetch_object()) {
    $result[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Now the success function won't execute anymore :(

Comment: So I found the error message and it saids  Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object. I changed my code like you said but it's hanging on the line i marked.
http://hastebin.com/kafeyipaca.parser3

Comment: You might have some error in your connection or query.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
```

As it takes array as parameter. Check [**here**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Just a note :
If are sure you will return json data, use dataType:json , so you wont need `JSON.parse(output)`.

Comment: without declaring `$result = array();` or `$result = [];` it will not add all the rows in `$result[]` array.

Comment: @Noman , yes , it there is no further processing, we can eliminate variable . Thanks